# Nativescript delete image from library

Tags: nativescript

I have a NS 4.1 with TS application.  In it, I am allowing the user to select an image using [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker).

If the user chosses to do so, I want to remove the image from the device.  I am using the following code:

```js
//files is a list of file locations: e.g./storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_1529637637242.jpg

import * as fs from 'tns-core-modules/file-system';
files.forEach(f => {
 let file: fs.File = fs.File.fromPath(f);
 if (file)
  file.remove();
});
```

When code runs, the file is actually deleted, but it is still showing in the library.  What do I need to do to remove it from the Library as well?

Currently testing on Android, but will need the same functionality on iOS.

NOTE:  If I try to open the file from the library I get a message that the image cannot be displayed and then it disappears from the view.  The questions is hoiiw to refresh the library after the file is deleted.

Comment: may be path from library is different from DCIM so you have to remove it too as well

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger media scanner manually for given path. which will reflect the changes.
here is the code for android

```
    android.content.Intent mediaScanIntent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    android.net.Uri contentUri = android.net.Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    application.android.context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

or you can also do below

```
    android.media.MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(application.android.context, [picturePath], null, callback);
```