# delete media from library and refreshing gallery

Tags: nativescript-vue

found this question and answer on stackoverflow [Nativescript delete image from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993790/nativescript-delete-image-from-library)

I am new to nativescript and when I do like suggested i get the following error:

'[TypeError: Cannot read property 'MediaScannerConnection' of undefined]'

I guess i need to import this somehow
what do i need to do to be able to use the android.media classes ?

...

```
              const thefile = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(path);
              thefile.remove();
```

...

The above is working just fine - but when i pick another image the deleted image still appears in the gallery - This is the suggested code from the other question

...

```
              var callback = new android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener(
                {
                  onScanCompleted: function(path, uri) {
                    console.log("media scan");
                    console.log(path);
                  },
                }
              );

            android.media.MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
              applicationModule.android.context,
              path,
              null,
              callback
            );
```

...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nativescript delete image from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993790/nativescript-delete-image-from-library)

Comment: that is the question i am referring to at the top - my question is about what i need to do to be able to use android.media.MediaScannerConnection in my native app

Answer (score 0):

I had this above because i thought i should import something to be able to use the android var (brand new to nativescript developement) - so after removing this statement the android var worked as i should - without me messing it up :-)

const android = require("tns-core-modules/application/application");